# Django: how to use the nice admin tables in the actual application

Tags: django

New to Django, just worked through the 'polls' tutorial. Now I would like to convert those simple views into tabular views, just as in the pretty admin interface. Should I try to clone code from the admin module? Otherwise, how to proceed?

Comment: Are you comfortable with HTML? You can prettify them without changing your Django code.

Comment: Prettifying is one aim. But I also want to add functionality. Very much the same kind of functionality as in the admin interface. So, HTML is not the solution; if it were, I wouldn't use Django. - I guess, things like `admin.TabularInline` also exist outside the admin module. My question is: how find them? where to find a working example?

Comment: In the meantime, I found https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1442/ of 2009: "As there is no straight way to re-produce the real tabular inline formsets you get in django-admin, ..."

Comment: This one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975179 is also four years old - is it still state of the art?

Comment: The snippet still works if you comfortable with django formsets

Comment: Since you're exploring forms, have a look at Crispy Forms. http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ by adding a FormHelper and Layout definition to your Django form you can customize your form easily and quickly render the form bootstrap-style (or some other style).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The admin forms are just Django [forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/#forms) and [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/formsets/#formsets). To build a form for your model you use [modelforms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/modelforms/). Maybe nice to look at the admin tabular_inline template. It lives at: django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/edit_inline/tabular.html.

The snippet is [looping over the form fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields).